# .htaccess rewrite files that don't exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've seen a few examples online, and some answers here on stackoverflow. I haven't found any yet that have suited my needs. Let me start off by saying I have very little experience with .htaccess and I am doing more research on it by reading tutorials and examples online.

Hopefully someone can explain what I am doing wrong here... I don't want the file to send a redirect header, rather mask the URL they are going to if it DOESN'T exist, with another URL.

Example:

I go to non-existent page (e.g. 404):

```
http://example.com/hello-everyone
```

Instead of displaying the 404, I'd rather it display the content from

```
http://example.com/?/hello-everyone
```

Note* I don't want a redirect header, as I don't want people to have to see the ?/ prefix.

Thanks!

Comment: What will handle the requests. A script, for example, `index.php` or `handler.php`? If so, what's the parameter you want to pass to that resource? Should be `hello-everyone` in this case.

Comment: The index already handles the data passed to the ?/ already, I just need it so that if someone forgets the ?/, that it will still work without any redirect. And that's correct, hello-everyone would be the passing argument.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. At this moment, URLs like this one  `http://example.com/?/hello-everyone` are already passed to `index.php`, but you want these ones `http://example.com/hello-everyone` to be passed too to `index.php`? Please correct me if I  am wrong.

Comment: That's correct. It's as if I was doing this: `http://ex.com/?title=hello-everyone` but wouldn't want people to see ?title= and would rather the URL to look like this: `http://ex.com/hello-everyone`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   index.php?key=%1  [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://www.mywebsite.com/val`

To

`http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?key=val`

Where `key` is any fixed key name and `val' is the variable value in the incoming URL.

`/val` must be the last string in the incoming URL for the rules to work.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`

Using this type of incoming URLs `http://www.mywebsite.com/val` might allow you in the future to stop using the more hard to remember URLs `http://www.mywebsite.com/?/val` used at this moment.

Comment: Bravo. Worked flawlessly! Cheers mate